# How to develop a tf.data object from a generator that only outputs a list of arrays?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to develop a tf.data object that yields a list of arrays, but I am getting a data mismatch error. Here's my attempt

```
def labelGen():
    yield tf.constant([1, 0], dtype=tf.int64), tf.constant([1, 0], dtype=tf.int64), tf.constant([0, 1], dtype=tf.int64), tf.constant([0, 1], dtype=tf.int64)

Labeldataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     labelGen, (tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64), ([], [], [], [], []) )

list(Labeldataset.take(1))
```

And this is the error I get

> InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was (tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64), but the yielded element was (, , , ).
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the number of items in .from_generator code didn't match. 
Second, the generator should be called without ().
Here is working code tested in TF 2.1.

```
def labelGen():
    yield tf.constant([1, 0], dtype=tf.int64), tf.constant([1, 0], dtype=tf.int64), tf.constant([0, 1], dtype=tf.int64), tf.constant([0, 1], dtype=tf.int64)

Labeldataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    labelGen, # without ()
    (tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64), # should match number of items
    (tf.TensorShape([2]), tf.TensorShape([2]), tf.TensorShape([2]), tf.TensorShape([2]))) # use tf.TensorShape

list(Labeldataset.take(1))
```

Result:

```
[(<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 0])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 0])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 1])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 1])>)]
```